# Standard Performance Matrix for iOS App

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-instruments

Is their any app vitals information or any standard values for iOS app to compare with, which is accepted and followed by developers.

Currently i am using Xcode instrument to detect memory leakage, app thread uses, core animation , rendering UI etc

But like in Google Play Store consoles which gives us the following metrics.

- Battery
- Excessive wakeups
- Stability
- Rendering
- Frozen Frames
- etc

Is their any standard values for iOS app also, if so kindly suggest were to look and update my app accordingly

Thanks

Comment: I think not available

Comment: They don't have metrics specifically. Have you seen [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html) document?

Comment: @Mrwerdo thanks , the document is really insitefull

Answer (score 2):

Apple's developer website contains many articles covering various performance topics. In particular their [Energy Efficiency Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015243-CH3-SW1) seems to parallel Google Play Store's metrics.

You can find their articles by searching in the [Apple Developer Center](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/navigation/) for 'performance'.

[image]